# Can CodeDeploy be used with a stand alone Git server?

Tags: aws-code-deploy

Does anyone know if it's possible to make CodeDeploy work with a generic Git server rather than GitHub or S3?

Answer (score 1):

CodeDeploy does not support generic Git servers. The GitHub URL is hardcoded into the agent. (See https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/blob/master/lib/instance_agent/codedeploy_plugin/command_executor.rb#L216) Of course, the agent is open source, so it would be fairly easy to change this.